# Symfony 4 skeleton, error on calling php binance api and php binance api rate limiter

Tags: php, api, symfony4, binance

I want to call the Binance\API and Binance\RateLimiter in the controller, but because these two class have the same namespace. Symfony4 is returning an error 
"Attempted to load class "RateLimiter" from namespace "Binance".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

here my sample code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Binance;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky", name="lucky")
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $api = new Binance\API();
        $api = new Binance\RateLimiter($api);

        while(true) {
           print_r($api->history("BTCUSDT"));
           exit();
        }

    }
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You could just use fully qualified names instead of a use statement. Maybe it's getting confused because of the relative namespace references.

Comment: Yep, try to use full namespaces instead of partial

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Binance\API as BinanceAPI;
use Binance\RateLimiter as BinanceRateLimiter;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky", name="lucky")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
        $api = new BinanceAPI();
        $api = new BinanceRateLimiter($api);
        
      
        print_r($api->history("BTCUSDT"));
        exit();
    }
}

Comment: The error still the same. Sorry about the format, I don't know how to format it in the add comment form.